# STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE In Open Watcom

Tags: c++

When I try to use a constant like STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE it gives me an error and says it doesn't exist. I'm guessing STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE must be included in Windows.H, which Open Watcom doesn't have, or at least it doesn't have in the 16bit compiler.

But if I include the "cstdlib" library I get the useful functions like SetConsoleTextAttribute() or System(), or other functions like that.

But a lot of functions I can't use, like SetConsoleTextAttribute(), for example, because they required the STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE as the first parameters.

Is there any way I could get around this? Or somehow include a different library in order to get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE?

Comment: I suggest you go over your old questions, and see if there are any acceptable answers, and then accept them. This will improve your accept rating and will make people more inclined to answer your questions.

Comment: I didn't even know you could accept answers until now. >.>
I'll do that, I guess.